# What is the command to get groupid of a group name in mac or linux?

Tags: linux, macos, macros

How can I get group id of a group in mac os or linux?

ie.,  Command GroupName  ==> should return the groupid

Eg:

```
Command staff   ==>   20
```

Comment: But this command was required for my product developement. i.e., in installation shell script

Comment: This is a valid and non-trivial question, and should be reopened.

Comment: @ulidtko: it's not valid for Stack Overflow, unfortunately, as the rules are rather stricter these days than they used to be. You're doing the right thing asking in SOCVR though.

Comment: OK, I posted a continuation on *nix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416102/how-to-resolve-a-group-name-to-gid-both-in-osx-and-linux/416106#416106

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Linux, you can use [getent(1)](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/getent.1.php):

```
$ getent group staff
staff:x:20:
```

If you only want 20:

```
$ getent group staff | cut -d: -f3
20
```

On OS X, you can use [dscl(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html):

```
$ dscl . -read /Groups/staff | awk '($1 == "PrimaryGroupID:") { print $2 }'
20
```

It can be easier to use this simple python command (using the [grp library](http://docs.python.org/library/grp.html)) to have the same result on both platforms:

```
$ python -c 'import grp; print grp.getgrnam("staff").gr_gid'
20
```

Comment: It can be done in ruby as well: `ruby -e 'require "etc"; puts Etc::getgrnam("staff").gid'`

Comment: more easy: `stat -c '%g' file-path` or for mac: `stat -f '%g' file-path`